# Does a mobile web site support sub menu?

Tags: android, mobile-website

I am developing a mobile website for android and I have multi level menus. What are all the ways to provide an effective navigation from page to page. Are there any specific standards that are to be followed.

Comment: Great question but you need to think more about how you phrase your title. Your question will come up in Google for eternity now and it would have been nice if the title match the great question. Only because, of course mobile supports sub menus. I found you because I'm trying to work out best way to display them for the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://jquerymobile.com. They have a web framework that looks nice in all the webkit based mobile browsers. If you click on the demo while in your phone, you'll see how nice it can look using their libraries.